# grep multiple strings, count lines, echo output for each string

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix

I want to grep multiple patterns from file and then print them with count. My patterns are like

```
Error code [61440] Error Description 
Error code [61000] Error Description 
Error code [61040] Error Description
```

`[]` contains numbers with variable length and also contain null, i can get count with following command, but to get that i have to see file and check number between `[]`.

```
cat  mylog.log |   grep  "Error code" | grep 61040 | wc -l
```

My desired output is like following

```
Error code [61440] = 90
Error code [61000] = 230
Error code [61040] = 567
```

Comment: Is `Error Description` a fixed string or can it vary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `cat  mylog.log |   grep  "Error code" | sort | uniq -c`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` to extract only the numbers inside `[]`, sort and count these.

```
$ sed 's/^.*\[\([0-9]*\)\].*$/\1/' < input | sort | uniq -c
1 61000
1 61040
1 61440
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne '$x{$1}++ if(/Error code \[([^\]]*)\] Error Description/);
           END{print "$_ => $x{$_}" for(keys %x)}' your_file
```

Tested:

```
> cat temp
Error code [61440] Error Description 
Error code [61000] Error Description 
Error code [61040] Error Description 
> perl -lne '$x{$1}++ if(/Error code \[([^\]]*)\] Error Description/);END{print "$_ => $x{$_}" for(keys %x)}' temp
61040 => 1
61000 => 1
61440 => 1
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `awk`

```
awk -F'[][]' '/Error code/ {a[$2]++} END { for (x in a) printf "Error code [%s] = %d\n", x, a[x] }' mylog.log
```

Output on your sample data

```
Error code [61440] = 1
Error code [61000] = 1
Error code [61040] = 1
```